# call function before plugin function starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a function to find highest value in an XML file from certain tag which has to assign one of default value in plugin. My problem is my plugin code runs before the other function hence a null value is returned. Can I run  function `get_Highest_Property_Prise()` before plugin, like java constructor? Or some how initialize a global variable before plugin code kicks in?

```
var pulgin_Global_Variables = {
    hight_price: ""
};

(function($) {

$.fn.SearchProperty = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        S_MinPrice: 0,
        S_MaxPrice: get_Highest_Property_Prise()
    };

     alert("yo yo "+defaults.S_MaxPrice);
}
})(jQuery);


function get_Highest_Property_Prise()
{


$.get('Data.xml', function (XML_property) {

    $(XML_property).find('property').each(function () {

        var c_Price = parseInt($(this).find('priceask').text().replace(',', ''));

        if (c_Price > pulgin_Global_Variables.hight_price) {

            pulgin_Global_Variables.hight_price = c_Price;
        }
    }); //end of function 

});
}
```

Comment: when are you invoking SearchProperty function?

Comment: i will call from html page just like calling other jquery functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pulgin_Global_Variables = {
    hight_price: ""
};  

  $.fn.SearchProperty = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        S_MinPrice: 0,
        S_MaxPrice: pulgin_Global_Variables.hight_price
    };

     alert("yo yo "+defaults.S_MaxPrice);
}
})(jQuery); 



//here set max price to match your global object
 $.get('Data.xml', function (XML_property) {
        $(XML_property).find('property').each(function () {

            var c_Price = parseInt($(this).find('priceask').text().replace(',', ''));

            if (c_Price > pulgin_Global_Variables.hight_price) {

                pulgin_Global_Variables.hight_price = c_Price;

            }
        }); //end of function 

    }).done(function () {
       $(whatever).SearchProperty()

})
```

Comment: you should call the prototype function when the original get has finished

Comment: is it safe to call get_Highest_Property_Prise() in the beginning of plugin ...  (function($) {

    get_Highest_Property_Prise();

Comment: i believe you could but don't think it's necessary to wrap the jQuery get call in a function unless the outside function is actually filtering something out or passing informing to .get

Comment: i dont understand one thing! I manage to change value dynamically of my global variable inside get_Highest_Property_Prise() function but inside plugin its not picking that value !!!

Comment: I guess I'd have to see more of your code to figure out what exactly you are trying to do